# angular dynamic css #

Tags: css, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

This is my css

```
#snackbar {
  float: bottom;
  visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-left: -125px;
  background-color: #009688;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 5%;
  top: 10%;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#snackbar.show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {top: 0; opacity: 0;} 
  to {top: 10%; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {top: 0; opacity: 0;}
  to {top: 10%; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {top: 10%; opacity: 1;} 
  to {top: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {top: 10%; opacity: 1;}
  to {top: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

Is that possible to change all top values from typescript i need to give top value from html using @Input and is that possible to replace css "top"  with css "bottom" by using angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ngClass:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>
```

I think there is no other ways.
Read more about ngClass here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: please demonstrate how to update value in top in my example

Comment: if you need to do css animations in angular app, you need to do it with angular animations, also it's good for performance. You can read this guide https://angular.io/guide/animations. I had the same problem and solve it with angular animations